# Debugbar de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Buenas

He clonado el repositorio https://github.com/laravel-enso/Enso el cual no consigo echar a andar y en la raíz me muestra pantalla en blanco.

https://github.com/jjmontalban/Enso

La debugbar de Laravel sólo me arroja esta info la cual no saco nada en claro. Alguna idea?

[image: Debugbar 1]

[image: Debugbar 2]

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Seguro qué es la "Debugbar"? ¿Puedes poner el código que está creando esta vista?

Comment: Primero, ten en cuenta que laravel/debugbar puede no estar 100% adecuado al entorno SPA. Segundo, ¿Por qué no abres un ticket en https://github.com/laravel-enso/Enso/issues? Seguro que ahi te ayudan, más que nada porque soy uno de los que resuelven los problemas ahi reportados. Pero el problema ha de ser reportado en inglés ya que ninguno hablamos español. **---** Esto ha sido traducido de la publicación original del autor de este comentario **---**